# Expectation maximization of moving average with binary source input

Tags: discrete-signals, estimation, system-identification, state-space

I am trying to do blind system identification of a univariate linear FIR model:

I am unsure if the approach is correct or not and any help to further proceed with the maximization will be great. Thank you.

Comment: Your equations (1) and (2) do not make sense to me. How is $u(t)$ used? What is $w(t)$ in the paragraph below (2).  It *looks* like (1) should read something like: $z(t) = h_1 z(t-1) + h_2 z(t-2) + w(t)$ for this to start to make sense... Or is it something else?

Comment: I had made  a terrible blunder with the notations, thank you for telling me. I have corrected them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your E-step is correct(only one term missing in the last expression: $-N\ln\sigma_w$ ). 
To obtain the M-step you have to differentiate with respect to all your parameters. You don't have to include $u(n)$  in $\theta$, since it's defined by $p$. So you compute $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\theta}=0$. Solving for $\theta$, and this is your new $\theta$ i.e. $\theta_{m+1}$. E.g. for $h$ we gets $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial h}=-(-2\sum y_nz_n^s+2h\sum P_n^s)/(2\sigma_w^2)=0$.
Solving: $h=h_{m+1}=\sum y_nz_n^s(\sum P_n^s)^{-1}$.

-For $p$: 
$Q'(p)=\sum z_n^s/p -(N-\sum z_n^s)/(1-p)=0,p=\sum z_n^s/N$.

This is typical Bernoulli/binomial. So it seems right.

-For $\sigma_w$:
$Q'(\sigma_w)=-(\sum y_n^2-2h^T\sum y_nz_n^s+h^Th\sum P_n^s)\cdot (-2/(2\sigma_w^3))-N/\sigma_w=0,
\sigma_w^2=(\sum y_n^2-2h^T\sum y_nz_n^s+h^Th\sum P_n^s)/N$

and updating the parameters in a loop until convergence.